# Removing a certain number of filter views with Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-apps

I'm very interested in finding a way of deleting a given number of filter views by using Google APPs script. Currently I have several sheets with dozens of unnamed filter views that I need to delete. I can do it by hand, but this will take me several hours.

After doing some research, I have found one code snippet that allows to delete all the filter views in a given sheet, but I want to delete some of the filter views and not all of them.

This is the code Snippet I already found, courtesy of TheMaster:

```
function delFilterViews() {
  var ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(
    {
      requests: Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, {
        ranges: 'Sheet1', //Sheet in which filterviews are present
        fields: 'sheets/filterViews/filterViewId',
      }).sheets[0].filterViews.map(function(e) {
        return { deleteFilterView: { filterId: e['filterViewId'] } }; //create a new delete filter view request for each filter view present in sheet1
      }),
    },
    ssId
  );
}
```

The way I would like the script to work is to remove all the filter views for the current sheet which name begins with "Filter X"  X can be a number from 1 to 100

My crappy attempt at a regex would be something like this

`(Filter)\s\d*`

My current programming skills doesn't allow me to go much further than this.

Could anybody else help me with this?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to remove all filter views on the active sheet.
- You want to remove all filter views that the prefix of filter view title is `Filter`.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
function delFilterViews() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var get = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, {ranges: ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName(), fields: "sheets(filterViews(filterViewId,title))"});
  var resource = get.sheets.reduce(function(ar1, e) {
    if ("filterViews" in e) {
      var temp = e.filterViews.reduce(function(ar2, f) {
        if (/^Filter\s\d*/.test(f.title)) ar2.push({deleteFilterView: {filterId: f['filterViewId']}});
        return ar2;
      }, []);
      Array.prototype.push.apply(ar1, temp);
    }
    return ar1;
  }, []);
  if (resource.length > 0) Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: resource}, ssId);
}
```

#### References:

- [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your support. From OP's question, I couldn't understand the OP's goal as you suggested. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. So I added one more sample script for removing all filter views, which has the prefix of `Filter ` in the filter view title, in the active sheet. Thank you, again.

Comment: @Camilo Moreno I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and those samples were not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: HI @Tanaike. Thanks a lot for your help. The modifier script didn't work (nothing happened) but the Sample Script did work as intended. Perhaps for further reference, could you consider to just leave the  "sample script" in your answer to avoid confusion?

Comment: @Camilo Moreno Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And also, I updated my answer by removing "Modified script".